# Pegando informações de um select e passar num array

Tags: javascript, c#, array, asp.net-mvc-5

Quero pegar todos os campos de um `select` e armazena-los num `array`. pensei em fazer assim, mas não deu resultado.

```
var lista = [];
lista = $('#Model').text();
```

---

```
$('#Model').append('<option value="' + data.ModelID + '">' + data.Name + '</option>');
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** *No `click` de um botão*:

```js
var items = [];
$(function(){
  $('#btn1').on('click', function(){
    $('#select1 option').each(function(i,v)
    {
      items.push( {value: $(v).val(), text: $(v).text() } );
    });
    console.log(items);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="btn1">Transferir</button>
```

***2)*** *Ao carregar a página*:

```js
var items = [];
$(function()
{  
    $('#select1 option').each(function(i,v)
    {
      items.push( {value: $(v).val(), text: $(v).text() } );
    });
    console.log(items);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Obrigado Vigilio, mas ai neste caso tenho ID e tenho o texto, como faço para pegar os dois e armazenar?

Comment: @FabioSouza coloque seu `Select` na pergunta por favor

Comment: o select é alimentado com um json trazendo os resultados do banco

Comment: @FabioSouza fiz a edição!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fazer um loop nos itens do `select#Model`, e armazenar os dados de cada `<option>` no array.

```js
var dados = [];

$('#Model select').each(function (i, select) {
    dados.push({
        Name: select.innerHTML,
        ModelID: select.value
    });
});

// dados[0].Name
// dados[1].Name
```